# z-index for position:fixed?

Tags: html, css, z-index

Please tell me how to apply z-index if the covering element must have position: fixed? In this case, position:fixed; is applied to navigation, but it is on top of it that I need to display the menu button. How can this be done?

Here is my example, correctly displayed at full page.

Previously, I was helped in explaining how z-index works [in this example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60488202/why-doesnt-z-index-work-when-opening-the-menu?noredirect=1#comment107007340_60488202), but there was no such condition as position:fixed.

```js
  $('#nav-btn').on('click', function () {
    $('#nav-btn').toggleClass('open');
    $('.navigation').toggleClass('is-opened');
  });
```

```css
.navigation.is-opened {
    opacity: 1;
    pointer-events: auto;
    transition: opacity 0s 0s;
}

.navigation.is-opened .navigation__inner {
    -webkit-transform: translateX(0%);
    transform: translateX(0%);
}

.navigation {
    position: fixed;
    width: 100%;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    opacity: 0;
    z-index: 150;
    pointer-events: none;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-align: center;
    color: #fff;
    display: block;
    transition: opacity 0s 0.3s;
    -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
}

.navigation__inner {
    background-color: #0c1428;
    height: 100%;
    position: relative;
    width: 223px;
    margin-left: auto;
    max-width: 100%;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: flex;
    -ms-flex-direction: column;
    flex-direction: column;
    -webkit-transform: translateX(100%);
    transform: translateX(100%);
    transition: -webkit-transform 0.3s;
    transition: transform 0.3s;
    transition: transform 0.3s, -webkit-transform 0.3s;
}

.navigation__header {
    background-color: #0c1428;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
    height: 80px;
    z-index: 1;
    padding: 80px 0 0;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: flex;
    -ms-flex-align: center;
    align-items: center;
    -ms-flex-pack: center;
    justify-content: center;
    width: auto;
}

.navigation__content {
    padding-top: 80px;
    height: 100%;
    position: relative;
}

* {
    min-width: 0;
    min-height: 0;
    -webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0,0,0,0);
}

.navigation__menu {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 180px;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    padding: 40px 20px 40px 40px;
    -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
}

.navigation__content {
    padding-top: 80px;
    height: 100%;
    position: relative;
}

.head-panel {
    height: calc(100vh - 217px);
    position: relative;
}

.head-panel__slider-wr {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
}

}
.head-panel__slider {
    opacity: 1 !important;
}

.head-panel__content {
    position: relative;
    z-index: 1;
}

.head-panel__list {
    position: relative;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: flex;
    -ms-flex-wrap: wrap;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    height: calc(100vh - 217px);
}

.head-panel__section--center {
    position: relative;
    -ms-flex: 1 1;
    flex: 1 1;
    text-align: right;
    padding: 66px 297px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

.head-panel__section--last {
    padding: 64px 32px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    background: rgba(12,20,40,0.24);
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: flex;
    -ms-flex-direction: column;
    flex-direction: column;
    -ms-flex-pack: justify;
    justify-content: space-between;
    -ms-flex-align: center;
    align-items: center;
    max-width: 223px;
    min-width: 223px;
}

#nav-btn {
    width: 24px;
    height: 24px;
    position: relative;
    -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(0deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(0deg);
    transform: rotate(0deg);
    -webkit-transition: 0.5s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: 0.5s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: 0.5s ease-in-out;
    transition: 0.5s ease-in-out;
    cursor: pointer;
    z-index: 10;
}

#nav-btn {
  width: 24px;
  height: 24px;
  position: relative;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(0deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(0deg);
  transform: rotate(0deg);
  -webkit-transition: 0.5s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: 0.5s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: 0.5s ease-in-out;
  transition: 0.5s ease-in-out;
  cursor: pointer;
  z-index: 10;
}

#nav-btn span {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  height: 3px;
  width: 100%;
  background: #fff;
  border-radius: 9px;
  opacity: 1;
  left: 0;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(0deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(0deg);
  transform: rotate(0deg);
  -webkit-transition: 0.5s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: 0.5s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: 0.5s ease-in-out;
  transition: 0.5s ease-in-out;
  z-index: 999;
}

#nav-btn span:nth-child(1) {
  top: 0px;
  -webkit-transform-origin: left center;
  -moz-transform-origin: left center;
  -o-transform-origin: left center;
  transform-origin: left center;
}

#nav-btn span:nth-child(2) {
  top: 7px;
  -webkit-transform-origin: left center;
  -moz-transform-origin: left center;
  -o-transform-origin: left center;
  transform-origin: left center;
}

#nav-btn span:nth-child(3) {
  top: 14px;
  width: 70%;
  -webkit-transform-origin: left center;
  -moz-transform-origin: left center;
  -o-transform-origin: left center;
  transform-origin: left center;
}

#nav-btn.open span:nth-child(1) {
  will-change: transform;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-45deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(-45deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(-45deg);
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
  will-change: transform;
  top: 18px;
  width: 30px;
}

#nav-btn.open span:nth-child(2) {
  will-change: transform;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(30deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(45deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(45deg);
  transform: rotate(45deg);
  will-change: transform;
  top: -3px;
  width: 30px;
}

#nav-btn.open span:nth-child(3) {
  width: 0%;
  opacity: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <title></title>
</head>
<body class="app home">
 <div class="navigation">
  <div class="navigation__inner">
   <div class="navigation__header">
   </div>
   <div class="navigation__content">
    <div class="navigation__menu">
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>
 </div><!-- b:navigation -->
 <header class="app-header mt-4">
  <div class="head-panel">
   <div class="head-panel__slider-wr">
    <div class="head-panel__slider animator-zoomOfferScale animator owl-carousel owl-loaded" data-animator="zoomOfferScale"></div>
    <div class="head-panel__content">
     <div class="head-panel__list">
      <div class="head-panel__section head-panel__section--center animator-s9 animator-fadeInRight animator" data-animator="fadeInRight"></div>
      <div class="head-panel__section head-panel__section--last animator-s1 animator-fadeInRightBig animator" data-animator="fadeInRightBig">
       <div class="" id="nav-btn">
        <span></span> <span></span> <span></span>
       </div>
      </div>
     </div>
    </div>
   </div><!-- b:head-panel -->
  </div>
 </header>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are on right track just put `z-index` on parent container like below

```
.head-panel {
    z-index: 222;
}
```

As `head-panel` is first parent of your header.

```js
$('#nav-btn').on('click', function () {
    $('#nav-btn').toggleClass('open');
    $('.navigation').toggleClass('is-opened');
  });
```

```css
.navigation.is-opened {
    opacity: 1;
    pointer-events: auto;
    transition: opacity 0s 0s;
}

.navigation.is-opened .navigation__inner {
    -webkit-transform: translateX(0%);
    transform: translateX(0%);
}

.navigation {
    position: fixed;
    width: 100%;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    opacity: 0;
    z-index: 150;
    pointer-events: none;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-align: center;
    color: #fff;
    display: block;
    transition: opacity 0s 0.3s;
    -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
}

.navigation__inner {
    background-color: #0c1428;
    height: 100%;
    position: relative;
    width: 223px;
    margin-left: auto;
    max-width: 100%;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: flex;
    -ms-flex-direction: column;
    flex-direction: column;
    -webkit-transform: translateX(100%);
    transform: translateX(100%);
    transition: -webkit-transform 0.3s;
    transition: transform 0.3s;
    transition: transform 0.3s, -webkit-transform 0.3s;
}

.navigation__header {
    background-color: #0c1428;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
    height: 80px;
    z-index: 1;
    padding: 80px 0 0;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: flex;
    -ms-flex-align: center;
    align-items: center;
    -ms-flex-pack: center;
    justify-content: center;
    width: auto;
}

.navigation__content {
    padding-top: 80px;
    height: 100%;
    position: relative;
}

* {
    min-width: 0;
    min-height: 0;
    -webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0,0,0,0);
}

.navigation__menu {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 180px;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    padding: 40px 20px 40px 40px;
    -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
}

.navigation__content {
    padding-top: 80px;
    height: 100%;
    position: relative;
}

.head-panel {
    height: calc(100vh - 217px);
    position: relative;
    z-index: 222;
}

.head-panel__slider-wr {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
}

}
.head-panel__slider {
    opacity: 1 !important;
}

.head-panel__content {
    position: relative;
    z-index: 1;
}

.head-panel__list {
    position: relative;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: flex;
    -ms-flex-wrap: wrap;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    height: calc(100vh - 217px);
}

.head-panel__section--center {
    position: relative;
    -ms-flex: 1 1;
    flex: 1 1;
    text-align: right;
    padding: 66px 297px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

.head-panel__section--last {
    padding: 64px 32px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    background: rgba(12,20,40,0.24);
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: flex;
    -ms-flex-direction: column;
    flex-direction: column;
    -ms-flex-pack: justify;
    justify-content: space-between;
    -ms-flex-align: center;
    align-items: center;
    max-width: 223px;
    min-width: 223px;
}

#nav-btn {
    width: 24px;
    height: 24px;
    position: relative;
    -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(0deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(0deg);
    transform: rotate(0deg);
    -webkit-transition: 0.5s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: 0.5s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: 0.5s ease-in-out;
    transition: 0.5s ease-in-out;
    cursor: pointer;
    z-index: 10;
}

#nav-btn {
  width: 24px;
  height: 24px;
  position: relative;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(0deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(0deg);
  transform: rotate(0deg);
  -webkit-transition: 0.5s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: 0.5s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: 0.5s ease-in-out;
  transition: 0.5s ease-in-out;
  cursor: pointer;
  z-index: 10;
}

#nav-btn span {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  height: 3px;
  width: 100%;
  background: #fff;
  border-radius: 9px;
  opacity: 1;
  left: 0;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(0deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(0deg);
  transform: rotate(0deg);
  -webkit-transition: 0.5s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: 0.5s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: 0.5s ease-in-out;
  transition: 0.5s ease-in-out;
  z-index: 999;
}

#nav-btn span:nth-child(1) {
  top: 0px;
  -webkit-transform-origin: left center;
  -moz-transform-origin: left center;
  -o-transform-origin: left center;
  transform-origin: left center;
}

#nav-btn span:nth-child(2) {
  top: 7px;
  -webkit-transform-origin: left center;
  -moz-transform-origin: left center;
  -o-transform-origin: left center;
  transform-origin: left center;
}

#nav-btn span:nth-child(3) {
  top: 14px;
  width: 70%;
  -webkit-transform-origin: left center;
  -moz-transform-origin: left center;
  -o-transform-origin: left center;
  transform-origin: left center;
}

#nav-btn.open span:nth-child(1) {
  will-change: transform;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-45deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(-45deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(-45deg);
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
  will-change: transform;
  top: 18px;
  width: 30px;
}

#nav-btn.open span:nth-child(2) {
  will-change: transform;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(30deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(45deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(45deg);
  transform: rotate(45deg);
  will-change: transform;
  top: -3px;
  width: 30px;
}

#nav-btn.open span:nth-child(3) {
  width: 0%;
  opacity: 0;
}

.app-header{
z-index: 222;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <title></title>
</head>
<body class="app home">
 <div class="navigation">
  <div class="navigation__inner">
   <div class="navigation__header">
   </div>
   <div class="navigation__content">
    <div class="navigation__menu">
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>
 </div><!-- b:navigation -->
 <header class="app-header mt-4">
  <div class="head-panel">
   <div class="head-panel__slider-wr">
    <div class="head-panel__slider animator-zoomOfferScale animator owl-carousel owl-loaded" data-animator="zoomOfferScale"></div>
    <div class="head-panel__content">
     <div class="head-panel__list">
      <div class="head-panel__section head-panel__section--center animator-s9 animator-fadeInRight animator" data-animator="fadeInRight"></div>
      <div class="head-panel__section head-panel__section--last animator-s1 animator-fadeInRightBig animator" data-animator="fadeInRightBig">
       <div class="" id="nav-btn">
        <span></span> <span></span> <span></span>
       </div>
      </div>
     </div>
    </div>
   </div><!-- b:head-panel -->
  </div>
 </header>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but unfortunately it didn't work here (http://martinirus.cloud2.itstar.ru/)

Comment: @Gusar Its just becuse its first parent with class name `app-header` has `z-index: 5` So as i mention above set its first parent `z-index`... Try set `z-index` on `app-header`like this `.app-header {
    -ms-flex: none;
    flex: none;
    z-index: 222;
    position: relative;
}` ALSO Updated my ans

Comment: I updated the code and managed to put the button on top of the outgoing menu, but in addition to the menu call button, the social networks and search buttons are displayed on top. Please tell me, is it possible to bring up only the button and activate the links of the menu itself, or is it necessary to turn over the entire right block with its parent?
http://martinirus.cloud2.itstar.ru/

Comment: It mean you want to show only that toggle menu button but not social media and search button?

Comment: Yes, but I already did-I put the block with the menu under the block with social buttons and everything became as it should be. Thank you for your help!

Comment: @Gusar Glad to hear that you helped yourself, Much appreciated Cheers